# How can one can convert a Denso mapcode into GPS coordinates or a human-readable address?

Tags: japan, maps, gps-navigation

How can one can convert a [Denso mapcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denso_mapcode) (e.g., `549 544*88`) into GPS coordinates or a human-readable address?

All the resources I have found so far such as https://japanmapcode.com/en perform the conversion from GPS coordinates to Denso mapcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to find a site that does this conversion between numerous different formats, including plus codes.

The site is located here http://saibara.sakura.ne.jp/map/convgeo.cgi

Enter your map code under マップコード (make sure you also select the corresponding radio button for this option) and then click Send. The result will appear under 世界測地系

I note also that Denso have a "Drive! NIPPON" Android app that accepts these codes.

---

Screenshot from http://saibara.sakura.ne.jp/map/convgeo.cgi:

[image]